# Displaying Value Field from Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP and MySQL and am trying to write a code where I display all the values   of the column `value` where the column `attribute_id = 64`. This is what I have written but I can't seem to get it to display:

```
<? 
mysql_connect ("localhost","cpsdev_mage1","**********"); 
mysql_select_db ("cpsdev_mage1"); 

$sql = "select 'value' from mage_catalogsearch_fulltext 
WHERE 'Attribute_id' = 64"; 
$result = mysql_query ($sql) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['value'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Remove `'` surrounding `value` and `Attribute_id` in query.

Comment: Attribute_id or attribute_id ?? and remove also '...'

Comment: Try to write your code in <?php instead of <?  , var_dump($result) if no error reflecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code-

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost","cpsdev_mage1","**********"); 
mysql_select_db ("cpsdev_mage1"); 

$sql = "select value from mage_catalogsearch_fulltext WHERE Attribute_id = 64"; 
$result = mysql_query ($sql) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  echo $row['value'];
}

?>
```

What i added --

1. Changed `<?` to `<?php`.
2. Changed **'value'** to **value** & **'Attribute_id'** to **Attribute_id** in query.
3. Added `mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)`.

Comment: Okay its getting somewhere, no returns "Unknown column 'value' in 'field list'"

Comment: @SimonStaton Change value to the field name from which ur getting value..like if u have name field ain the db and you are fetching names from this query just replace the value to name..i guess it will help u now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
  $sql = "select value from mage_catalogsearch_fulltext WHERE Attribute_id = 64";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // instead of <?

  mysql_connect ("localhost","cpsdev_mage1","**********"); 
  mysql_select_db ("cpsdev_mage1"); 

  $sql = "SELECT value FROM mage_catalogsearch_fulltext 
  WHERE Attribute_id = 64"; // <------------ removed un-needed single quotes
  $result = mysql_query ($sql) or die("<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); // removed '$myQuery'

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['value'];
  }

?>
```

Comment: This type of DB connection has been depreciated, will pay you to look up PDO or mysqli

Comment: Okay thanks can see where I went wrong, the execution now returns this however: "Unknown column 'value' in 'field list'" the column value certainly exsists :s

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select value from mage_catalogsearch_fulltext WHERE Attribute_id = 64";
```

Also your code should begin with `<?php` not `<?`

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing the below query

```
          $sql = "select value from mage_catalogsearch_fulltext 
          WHERE 'Attribute_id' = 64";
```

In sql query columns do not need to be enclosed in quotes.
and also prefer using php full tags instead of short tags as in some servers short tags might be set to off which can create problems across different server environments